# LINQ to SQL handle autoincremented primary key

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I'm trying store data in a local database(SQL CE). I've set a property of RowObject like this:

```
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true,CanBeNull=false,IsDbGenerated=true,AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert,DbType="int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]
    public int key
    { get; set; }
```

and the primary key is automatically auto-incremented when I insert a new record. But if I remove one or more record and then I insert a new record, its primary key value corresponds at the primary key value of the last inserted record plus one, although that record was deleted.
I know it is not possible to update all primary keys. But, is it possible to control the increment of the primary key?and avoid the continuous increment of the primary key?

ok, thank you for your answer.  I ask because I'm worried that PK reaches its maximum value. Maybe this isn't a really problem for my project, but I want understand how handle it, in case it happens. And in case, if it is possible, how can I understand and handle if the database is completely full.

Comment: Why do you want your PK to be contiguous?  Do you have a legitimate reason, or do you just want your ids to "look nice"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's violating auto increment.

I sometimes due to need disable auto incrementation of a column to add a row which is deleted on the old place and then enable it again.

If you insist on doing so, you can add 2 triggers, in the delete trigger disable column's auto increment behaviour, then enable it again on another trigger which is after insert trigger.
So on delete disable it, on next insert add it with the max(ID)+1 and after insert enable it again.

For example:

-------------Person Table--------------

ID[Auto-Increment]----Name----Age
10000-------------------Jack-------21
10001-------------------Shawn----19
10002-------------------Albert-----33

```
Delete from Person where ID = 10002;  

set identity_insert AAA ON
```

now the next ID will be 10003 but you want 10002

```
DECLARE @ID int;  

select @ID = max(ID)+1 from Person  

Insert into Person(ID,Name,Age) values(@ID,'Mahdi',23)  

set identity_insert AAA OFF  --Auto Increments from now on
```

you should just check to see if you should insert your record with/without ID, I put that burden on your shoulder.

GOOD LUCK.